# Java Generics in a list, how to process List<MyClass<?>>

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a class, `MyObject<T>` and a list: `List<MyObject<?>>`.

Contents of the list (example):

- `MyObject<Date>();`
- `MyObject<Integer>();`

Then the `MyObject<T>` class contains a function:

```
public T getValue() {
    return this.someAttribute;
}
```

How can I iterate over my List and call the getValue method?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (myObject<?> obj : aList) {
    obj.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Myclass<?>> t  = new ArrayList<Myclass<?>>();
    Iterator<Myclass<?>> iter = t.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Myclass<?> next = iter.next();
        Object value = next.getValue();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Comment: The point is, the result of the item should be type specific. It is part of a parsing framework.

Comment: AS long as you use ?, you will not be able to get type specific results. From what I understand  from your problem, the best you can do is to use some form of MyClass<? extends MyType> and then get MyType as type during iteration.

Comment: @Jordi, Suraj is right.  So long as you have `List<MyObject<?>>` you're saying "I have a list that contains `MyObject`s of *some* type, but I don't know what that type is."  In that case there's *no way* you can use the specific type, because you've just implied that you don't know it.  If you **do** know it (e.g. it's `Double`), then declare the list as `List<MyObject<Double>>`.  If the type changes for different instance of the class, but is identical within a single instance, then generic parameterisation should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (MyObject obj : yourList){
   T value = obj.getValue();
}
```

Comment: I have some issues with this - firstly you're using the raw type `MyObject`, which is almost never a good thing (arguably should have been disallowed in the 1.5+ compilers) and you should provide *some* generic parameter.  Secondly, where is the parameter `T` defined?  The list is of type `List<MyObject<?>>`, so there's no assumption that a suitable `T` would be in scope.  Finally, the `getValue()` call will **not** return a `T` but will either return `Object` or `?` (depending on whether you address the second point), so this will either fail to compile or (correctly) raise an unchecked cast.

Answer (score 0):

> The point is, the result of the item should be type specific. It is part of a parsing framework.

The results can't be type specific, because your list contains a mixture of parametized `MyObject` (*Note* that I use upper case notation from now on...). The result will be of type `Object` and you'll have to use `instanceof` and cast.

Example code:

```
public class MyObject<T> {
  private T value;
  public T getValue() {return value;}

  // ...
}
```

Now we make a list snippet:

```
List<MyObject<?>> list = new ArrayList<MyObject<?>>(){
                               new MyObject<Integer>(), new MyObject<String>()};
for (MyObject<?> item:list) {
  Object itemValue = list.getValue();
}
```

From this example we see that we can't cast to any other type but `Object` - because the collection contains `MyObject` instances whose `getValue()` methods return `Integer` or `String`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem to call the method, the question is what you need to do with the return value.

```
for (MyObject<?> obj : aList) 
    call( obj );

static <T> call(MyObject<T> obj)
{
    T val = obj.getValue();
}
```

We can feed a `MyObject<?>` to `call()` method as a `MyObject<T>` arg, due to wildcard capture.